# Silverlight window boundaries

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, silverlight

say your silverlight area on a webpage is 200px by 200px.

you open a child window, is there a way to make it moveable outside the 200x200 silverlight area?

or say you drop down a combo box, let the drop down go out side of the 200x200 aea?

Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [Popup Outside the Bounds of the Silverlight Control](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3467352/popup-outside-the-bounds-of-the-silverlight-control)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry there isn't any practical way to do this.

(There are is a fairly ridiculous/heroic option suggested in the  duplicate thread mentioned in the comment above...)